# New Google Analytic set up not working

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to add google analytics code in my newly created app, but it is not working.

I think now the analytics set up guide is changed. I was following tutorial https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/start . I tried even sample app given there but it is also not working. Nothing is seen in real time or app overview.

When I tried giving property id of my previous apps with old set up guide (as shown below) it is working fine.

Below is code which I am using for my old apps:

```
//This is code from one of my activity.
      MyApplication m = new MyApplication();

                Tracker t = m.getTracker(
                        MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER,this);

        // Build and send an Event.
                t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                        .setCategory("analytics demo 123")
                        .setAction("Test")
                        .setLabel(null)
                        .build());

        //MyApplication class

        public class MyApplication extends Application {
            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();
                try {
                    Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
                }
                catch(Throwable ignore) {
                    // ignored
                }
            }

            // The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
            private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXXXXX-X";

            public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

            public enum TrackerName {
                APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
                GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
            }

            HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

            public MyApplication() {
                super();
            }

            synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId,Activity activity) {
                if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

                    GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(activity);
                    analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
                    Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                            : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);

                    t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
                    mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
                }
                return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
            }
        }
```

This code is working fine with old property ids, but as soon as I replace my old id with newly created one it is failing to track events.

When I followed new steps for setting up Google analytic it don't even show up in real time.

Does anyone facing the same issue? Please reply.

Comment: Did you try using the global tracker and did you update your property id in global_tracker?

Comment: Yes i tried. But as you can see m passing MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER in gettracker() method. so it won't look for global tracker.